# determine the frequency of a number if a simulation

Tags: matlab, simulation

I have the following function:

[image]

I have to generate 2000 random numbers from this function and then make a histogram.
then I have to determine how many of them is greater that 2 with P(X>2).

this is my function:

```
%function [ output_args ] = Weibullverdeling( X )
%UNTITLED Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
for i=1:2000
   % x= rand*1000;
    %x=ceil(x);
    x=i;
  Y(i) = 3*(log(x))^(6/5);
  X(i)=x;
end
plot(X,Y)
```

and it gives me the following image: [image]

how can I possibly make it to tell me how many values Do i Have more than 2?

Comment: Usually in random variate generation and simulation, `U` is used to denote a uniform random number between 0 and 1.  The log of that would be negative, so unless lambda is also negative I think your formula is wrong.  Additionally, the equation has lambda under the root, but your Matlab formula has it outside the power. Would you please clarify what the pieces of your formula are supposed to be, and that you transcribed it correctly?

Comment: Your code doesn't return your task. So either you have an error in your code or an error in your formulation of what you should do. Right now you plot your equation from 1 to 2000. In steps of 1. So you have no random (or uniform) distribution at all. In your text you say you have to "generate 2000 random numbers from this function". This would indicate you should compute log(x) for 2000 random number most likely between 2 boarders which you have not told us. Pls edit your question to explain which one is right.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple:

```
>> Y_greater_than_2 = Y(Y>2);
>> size(Y_greater_than_2)
ans =

      1   1998
```

So that's 1998 values out of 2000 that are greater than 2.

**EDIT**

If you want to find the values between two other values, say between 1 and 4, you need to do something like:

```
>> Y_between = Y(Y>=1 & Y<=4);
>> size(Y_between)
ans =

   1   2
```

Comment: I tried this to also get the values bwtween (1 <= X <= 4), and it still gave me 1 1998, so I think this answer is not correct.: this is how I did it: Y_between = Y(1<=Y<=4); then size(Y_between).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I think:

```
for i=1:2000
  x=rand(1);
  Y(i) = 3*(log(x))^(6/5);
  X(i)=x;
end
plot(X,Y)
```

U is a uniform random variable from which you can get the X. So you need to use rand function in MATLAB.

After which you implement:

```
size(Y(Y>2),2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the code directly (here `k` is your root, `n` is number of data points, `y` is the highest number of distribution, `x` is smallest number of distribution and `lambda` the `lambda` in your equation):

```
X=(log(x+rand(1,n).*(y-x)).*lambda).^(1/k);
result=numel(X(X>2));
```

**Lets split it and explain it detailed:**

You want the k-th root of a number:

```
number.^(1/k)
```

you want the natural logarithmic of a number:

```
log(number)
```

you want to multiply sth.:

```
numberA.*numberB
```

you want to get lets say 1000 random numbers between x and y:

```
(x+rand(1,1000).*(y-x))
```

you want to combine all of that:

```
x= lower_bound;
y= upper_bound;
n= No_Of_data;   
lambda=wavelength; %my guess 
k= No_of_the_root;
X=(log(x+rand(1,n).*(y-x)).*lambda).^(1/k);
```

So you just have to insert your `x,y,n,lambda` and `k`

and then check

```
bigger_2 = X(X>2);
```

which would return only the values bigger than 2 and if you want the number of elements bigger than 2

```
No_bigger_2=numel(bigger_2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go with the assumption that what you've presented is supposed to be a random variate generation algorithm based on inversion, and that you want real-valued (not complex) solutions so you've omitted a negative sign on the logarithm. If those assumptions are correct, there's no need to simulate to get your answer.

Under the stated assumptions, your formula is the inverse of the complementary cumulative distribution function (CCDF). It's complementary because smaller values of U give larger values of X, and vice-versa. Solve the (corrected) formula for U.  Using the values from your Matlab implementation:

```
      X = 3 * (-log(U))^(6/5)
  X / 3 = (-log(U))^(6/5)
-log(U) = (X / 3)^(5/6) 
      U = exp(-((X / 3)^(5/6)))
```

Since this is the CCDF, plugging in a value for X gives the probability (or proportion) of outcomes greater than X. Solving for X=2 yields 0.49, i.e., 49% of your outcomes should be greater than 2.

Make suitable adjustments if lambda is inside the radical, but the algebra leading to solution is similar. Unless I messed up my arithmetic, the proportion would then be 55.22%.

If you still are required to simulate this, knowing the analytical answer should help you confirm the correctness of your simulation.